# How to change Android's Programmable Buttons Settings programmatically?

Tags: java, android, button, keyevent

My android app is succesfully detecting when "special" physical buttons are being pressed in the device. These buttons are the PTT (Push to Talk) and Red (SOS) buttons in a
**Crosscall CORE X5 device**. I press the buttons and everything runs well.

The Problem:
Initially my app was not reacting when the PTT and SOS buttons were pressed, because by factoring settings in:
Android Settings > Buttons > Programmable Button 1,2,3,4...
...both programmable buttons were set to open system apps like the Camera or the Virtual Assistant.

The Workaround
I had to set Programmable buttons 1 and 2 to "Not Configured" so my app could react properly to button press events.

My Question
Is there a way to set Programmable Buttons to "Not configured" programmatically?[image]

Comment: Found any solution Josh ?

Comment: @Nawal No, the manufacturer said they would fix it in subsequent updates. Not sure if they already fixed it.

Comment: How were you getting the button callbacks? I couldn't find the intent actions for button 3 and 4 to listen them on broadcast receiver.